three-point explicit schemes for the linear advection equation
Here is the full assignment:
Consider three-point explicit schemes for the linear advection equation on the real
line of the form
$$
u_{j}^{n+1}=u_{j}^n-C\left(u_{j}^n-u_{j-1}^n\right)+D\left(u_{j+1}^n-u_{j}^n\right) .
, \tag{1}$$
Show that
$$
\sum_j\left|u_j^{n+1}-u_{j-1}^{n+1}\right| \leq \sum_j\left|u_j^n-u_{j-1}^n\right|
, \tag{2}$$
If $C \geq 0$, $D \geq 0$, and $C + D \leq1$
Model "solution":
$$
u_{j-1}^{n+1}=u_{j-1}^n-C\left(u_{j-1}^n-u_{j-2}^n\right)+D\left(u_j^n-u_{j-1}^n\right) .
, \tag{3}$$
En soustrayant $\mathrm{Eq}(3)$ from $\mathrm{Eq}(1)$ we get
$$
u_j^{n+1}-u_{j-1}^{n+1}=(1-C-D)\left(u_j^n-u_{j-1}^n\right)+C\left(u_{j-1}^n-u_{j-2}^n\right)+D\left(u_{j+1}^n-u_j^n\right) ., \tag{4}
$$
We take the absolute value of both sides, use the triangle inequality on the right-side as well as the fact that $|1-C-D|=(1-C-D),|C|=C$, and $|D|=D$, and then sum the two sides over all $j$ on we get:
$$
\sum_j\left|u_j^{n+1}-u_{j-1}^{n+1}\right| \leq(1-C-D) \sum_j\left|u_j^n-u_{j-1}^n\right|+C \sum_j\left|u_{j-1}^n-u_{j-2}^n\right|+D \sum_j\left|u_{j+1}^n-u_j^n\right| .  \tag{5}
$$
The right-side simplifies to give
$$
\sum_j\left|u_j^{n+1}-u_{j-1}^{n+1}\right| \leq \sum_j\left|u_j^n-u_{j-1}^n\right| , \tag{6}
$$
My question is the following
I didn't understand how do we get the inequality (6) ?
is $j$ start from - $\infty$ ?

If I assume that $n$ is the temporal variable index, and $j$ is the spatial variable index (which should be the case given the stability result you want to show), then $j$ runs from the left end point of the grid.
Without loss of generality, $j$ can be assumed to start with 0 and there is only trivial inflow BC at this point with a advection velocity pointing to the right i.e., $u^n_0 \equiv 0$ for any $n\geq N_0$. Then, every $u$ with a negative index is zero. For example, at the $j=1$, the split reads
$$
u^{n+1}_1 - u^{n+1}_0 = (1 - C -D) (u^n_1 - u^{n}_0) + C u^{n}_0 + D(u^{n}_2 - u^{n}_1)
$$
so the contribution from the second term on the right of $(5)$ is 0. For the non-boundary involved terms, simply shifting the indices in the second and the third terms in $(5)$ will result them to be canceled with part of the first term.

Is this the  method of shifting the indices : in the second terms give $C \sum_{j=0}\left|u_{j-1}^n-u_{j-2}^n\right|=C \sum_{j'=-1}\left|u_{j'}^n-u_{j'-1}^n\right|$ with j'=j-1 and $C \sum_{j'=-1}\left|u_{j'}^n-u_{j'-1}^n\right|=C \sum_{j'=0}\left|u_{j'}^n-u_{j'-1}^n\right|+\left|u_{-1}^n-u_{-2}^n\right|$ since the negative terms equals to $0$ and $j'$ is mute variable

@ Shuhao Cao Thank you very much how can shifting the indices in the second and the third terms in (5)
